# Como faço para pegar um valor de uma célula no R?

Tags: r, string

Importei meus dados que estavam numa planilha do *Excel* para o *R*, colocando-os numa variável chamada `umParticipante`.

Entretanto, quando faço o seguinte código:

```
umParticipante.nome <- umParticipante[5,1]
print(umParticipante.nome)
```

Ele *printa*:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  ..1                          
  <chr>                        
1 Subject name: fulano
```

Mas eu gostaria que `umParticipante.nome` ficasse somente com a *string* correspondente ao nome do participante. No caso, gostaria que o código `print(umParticipante.nome)` retornasse `fulano`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o argumento `drop = TRUE`.

O código deve ficar assim:

`umParticipante[5, 1, drop = TRUE]`

**Explicação:**

Quando você passa o argumento `drop = TRUE`, o R transforma o resultado em um vetor e ficará do jeito que você espera.

Já se você não passar o argumento `drop`, ou passar `drop = FALSE`, o resultado é transformado em um novo `tibble` com apenas uma linha e coluna.